# push в удалённый репозиторий на bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-key

Привет. Пытаюсь запушить проект на *bitbucket* по *ssh*. Но не могу настроить права.

Проделал все действия, как сказано [здесь](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-ssh2). Получаю это:

> authenticated via a deploy
>
> You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
>
> This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:
>
> LIST OF USERS

По ссылке не фигурирует строка:

> This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:

Что это означает выяснить мне не удалось. Подскажите, что делать? Что такое `deploy key`? И как мне получить права на зпись, при условии, что в настройках прав у меня стоят права на запись.

Я задал вопрос в тех. поддержку. [Здесь](https://getsupport.atlassian.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/35/CA-332402) его можно найти.

Comment: *\You do not have permission to view this request.*

Comment: @0andriy Шта? О чём Вы?

Comment: Вопрос, о чём *вы*? Этого как раз и не удаётся прочитать.

Comment: @0andriy поправил читаемость. Так лучше? Понятнее? Был в пьяном угаре.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Связана она была с особенностями хранения ключей в *bitbucket*. Заключается она в том, что коль скоро Вы хотите делать коммиты в удалённый репозиторий, Вам необходимо добавить ssh-ключ в свой аккаунт, а не в конкретный репозиторий.

Вот, что ответили специалисты *bitbucket*:

> Hi there, Thank you for the feedback and, sorry for my mistake. The
>   "access keys" under the repository settings are used to gain read-only
>   access only to a repository. If you want to have write and admin
>   access to a repository through SSH authentication, you will need to
>   add the key on your account, not in your repository. Let us know if
>   you have any questions. 
>   Kindly regards,  Gabriel Marcolino,  Atlassian Support

Таким образом, добавление ключа в репозиторий == *права на чтение*. Добавление ключа в аккаунт == *права на запись*.